# Overriding an array function for a single instance

Tags: javascript, arrays, overriding

I'm trying to write a custom push function and only override it for a single instance. I'm trying to wire it up so every time I push to this array I can trigger my extra code. I don't want to override it for all Arrays or create a custom class if I don't have to.

First I had this:

```
let user_progress = {completed: [], inprogress: [] }
user_progress.completed.push = (item) => {
    Array.prototype.push.call(user_progress.completed, item)


    //do extra stuff


    common.store_data(user_progress, RESOURCE_COLLECTION)
    return undefined;
}
```

Then I tried this:

```
let Progress = function(){
this.completed = new Array()
this.inprogress = new Array() 
}
let user_progress = new Progress()

user_progress.completed.push = (item) => {
    Array.prototype.push.call(user_progress.completed, item)
    common.store_data(user_progress, RESOURCE_COLLECTION)
    return undefined;
}
```

user_progress.completed.push(item) works the first time you call it then it gets overwritten and becomes the standard Array.push. I assume it has something today with the Array.Prototype.push.call() and passing in user_progress.completed. What am i doing wrong? Both don't work and have the same issue. What is going on in the background here and is there an easy fix?

Comment: `new Progress()` sets `completed` to `new Array()`, which overwrites the custom `push`. Move the definition of `push` into the constructor of `Progress`. Or think about using a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

Comment: Thanks! I forgot function definitions are hoisted and was foolishly thinking new Progress() resolved first